# Set limits on y axis for two dependent variables using facet_grid()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe

```
            Condition  congruency Distance Measure   Score  liminf  limsup    ConditionF MeasureF
     1           Zero     Neutral        0     RTs 445.000 435.000 455.000          Zero      RTs
     2           Zero   Congruent        1     RTs 445.000 435.000 456.000          Zero      RTs
     3           Zero   Congruent        2     RTs 441.000 430.000 451.000          Zero      RTs
     4           Zero   Congruent        3     RTs 432.000 422.000 442.000          Zero      RTs
     5           Zero Incongruent        1     RTs 449.000 439.000 459.000          Zero      RTs
     6           Zero Incongruent        2     RTs 449.000 438.000 460.000          Zero      RTs
     7           Zero Incongruent        3     RTs 453.000 440.000 465.000          Zero      RTs
     8  All different     Neutral        0     RTs 446.000 436.000 456.000 All different      RTs
     9  All different   Congruent        1     RTs 445.000 434.000 455.000 All different      RTs
     10 All different   Congruent        2     RTs 449.000 438.000 461.000 All different      RTs
     11 All different   Congruent        3     RTs 449.000 438.000 461.000 All different      RTs
     12 All different Incongruent        1     RTs 446.000 436.000 456.000 All different      RTs
     13 All different Incongruent        2     RTs 447.000 436.000 458.000 All different      RTs
     14 All different Incongruent        3     RTs 450.000 440.000 461.000 All different      RTs
     15          Zero     Neutral        0  Errors   0.029   0.018   0.039          Zero   Errors
     16          Zero   Congruent        1  Errors   0.023   0.015   0.031          Zero   Errors
     17          Zero   Congruent        2  Errors   0.023   0.014   0.033          Zero   Errors
     18          Zero   Congruent        3  Errors   0.027   0.018   0.036          Zero   Errors
     19          Zero Incongruent        1  Errors   0.034   0.024   0.044          Zero   Errors
     20          Zero Incongruent        2  Errors   0.036   0.024   0.048          Zero   Errors
     21          Zero Incongruent        3  Errors   0.024   0.013   0.035          Zero   Errors
     22 All different     Neutral        0  Errors   0.019   0.013   0.026 All different   Errors
     23 All different   Congruent        1  Errors   0.028   0.017   0.038 All different   Errors
     24 All different   Congruent        2  Errors   0.021   0.011   0.032 All different   Errors
     25 All different   Congruent        3  Errors   0.031   0.022   0.041 All different   Errors
     26 All different Incongruent        1  Errors   0.024   0.010   0.037 All different   Errors
     27 All different Incongruent        2  Errors   0.020   0.011   0.029 All different   Errors
     28 All different Incongruent        3  Errors   0.019   0.010   0.028 All different   Errors
```

I want to make a line graph for RTs and Errors (my DVs. Because I want to put them together in the same graph space, I am using face_grid for this:

```
ggplot(matriz, aes(Distance, Score, shape= congruency, linetype=congruency)) + 
    geom_point(size=5) + 
    geom_line(size=1) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = limsup, ymin= liminf), width=0.25, linetype=1)  + 
    facet_grid(MeasureF~ConditionF,scales= "free")
```

the thing is that I would like to customize each y axis. Specifically, I want to set limits for this axis. This is quite simple if I had a simple graph (I would only need to include the instruction `coord_cartesian()`), but I don't have idea of how to do it when I use `facet_grid()`.

Comment: You currently cannot do this with facet_grid() I believe. But if the graphs do not share a common scale at all (i.e. you're just "putting them together"), then facet_grid() isn't really intended for that anyway. Try using `grid.arrange` from the gridExtra package instead.

Comment: @joran   Being able to expand the y-axis ranges with facet_grid is very helpful when you want to quickly compare different time series on the same range of data (using top to down subplot arrangements).  For example, comparing the daily price of a stock price over time to the daily volatility of the stock price, all on the same graph/view.  grid.arrange is nice, but you have to carefully adjust the x-axis values so that the plots line up nicely with the correct x dates/times.

Comment: @Clay ggplot intentionally makes it difficult to make plots with dual y axis scales (which is essentially what you are describing) because it is widely considered to be bad graphical practice. Whether you happen to find it useful or not doesn't change the fact that facet_grid does not give you the ability to adjust the y axes directly or that `grid.arrange` is a reasonable alternative. Adjusting the data directly, as you show, is also another option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to expand the y-limits for a plot with faceting in ggplot2, you could do the following approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
set.seed(1)
N <- 24

dates = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-01"), by = "1 month")
dummy_data <- data.frame(dates = dates, x = rnorm(N,0,1), group = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size = N, replace = TRUE))
dummy_data_m  <- melt(dummy_data, id.vars = c("dates", "group"))

plot = ggplot(data = dummy_data_m, aes(x = dates, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(group ~., scales="free_y")

print(plot) # Want to modify y-axis on this plot for each panel


# to expand plot axes, build the y ranges in a data.frame and add a new layer to the plot using geom_blank

# pick an x.value in the range of your x-values in dummy_data
x.value = as.Date("2014-01-01")
x.value = as.Date("2014-01-01")

# Say you want to expand the y-axis ranges for the different subpanels to be (-5, 5), (-4, 4), (-2, 2).  
# If you simply plot at this point the y limits are roughly ~(-1.5, 1.5) for each plot
lower_y = data.frame(dates = x.value, group = c("A", "B", "C"),  value = c(5, 4, 2))

y_ranges = rbind(lower_y, upper_y)
y_ranges_m = melt(y_ranges, id.vars = c("dates", "group"))
plot = plot + geom_blank(data = y_ranges_m, aes(x = dates, y = value, colour = variable))

print(plot)
```

For the opposite case, if you want to decrease the y range, then remove observations from the data in the panels for which you want to shrink the y-axis.  For example (instead of expanding the y-axis as above):

```
# do not want to plot any values where y < 0 for group A

dummy_data2 = dummy_data

x_adjusted = dummy_data2$x

x_adjusted[x_adjusted < 0 & dummy_data2$group == "A"] = NA

dummy_data2$x = x_adjusted

dummy_data_m2  <- melt(dummy_data2, id.vars = c("dates", "group"))

plot = ggplot(data = dummy_data_m2, aes(x = dates, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(group ~., scales="free_y")
print(plot) # this will show a plot where the panel for A has a y-axis lower limit above 0
```